# pass data from grid control (divexpress) to database by linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, linq

I try to pass data from grid control in dev express to database 
I try with this code but make an error.

```
var items = gridView1.DataSource;
            foreach (var row in items)
            {
                row.Invoice_ID = invoice.ID;
                row.Trip_ID = tr.ID;
                db.Invoice_Details.InsertOnSubmit(row);
```

[image]

Comment: Edit question to show exact error message. Should there be a closing } in that code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the datasource of the grid control. Not the Grid view.
1. Get data from your database then put it into a datatable.
2. Use Gridcontrol.datasource = datatable

Comment: i have 4 rows in grid control  and I want to save it to table in database